# Extract a value from a Custom Javascript array when it's a component of a string value within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

I'm looking to extract the values 'adult' and '2ndclass' from this custom javascript array in separate javascript variables for each value. Anyone has any ideas on how to do this?

In the following case, there are 2 products added to cart but I would like to have the flexibility to always grab any existing values for each product that is added to cart regardless of the amount added. Is that possible?

```js
[
  'pass/DE-NO-RS-BE-FI-PT-BG-DK-LT-LU-HR-LV-FR-HU-SE-SI-ME-SK-GB-IE-MK-EE-CH-GR-IT-ES-AT-CZ-PL-RO-NL-TR-BA/**adult/2ndclass**',
  'pass/DE-NO-RS-BE-FI-PT-BG-DK-LT-LU-HR-LV-FR-HU-SE-SI-ME-SK-GB-IE-MK-EE-CH-GR-IT-ES-AT-CZ-PL-RO-NL-TR-BA/**youth/2ndclass**'
]
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "custom" javascript array?

Comment: I meant i'm using a custom javascript variable in GTM to extract that bit of info I pasted at the top and put it into an array. So essentially what i'm trying to do here is grab these 2 components from that array. Hope it clarifies and thanks for checking

Answer (score 0):

First of all i didn't get your question completely. But as far as i can understand you want those 2 values at the end of the strings from an array. You can try something like this

```
var a, b;
for(s in YOUR_ARRAY){
    [...other, a, b] = YOUR_ARRAY[s].split("/");
    console.log(a, b);
    //Do whatever you want to do with a,b 
}
```

Let me explain myself, Firstly you would require to iterate over your array thats why we have a 'for' loop here. Then for each string which is given by 'YOUR_ARRAY[s]' you are splitting the string with '/' as a delimiter. Rest of the thing is pretty simple.
For your reference go through these links
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

**UPDATE:**
As mentioned in the comments. If you want to have a function for this then

```
function processValues(arr){
    var a, b;
    for(s in arr){
        [...other, a, b] = arr[s].split("/");
        console.log(a, b);
        //Do whatever you want to do with a,b 
   }
}

processValues(YOUR_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Taranjeet, can't seem to figure out how I can transform this bit into a custom javascript variable using the function () { and return commands

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **RegExp** to get those values out.

```
var arr = [
    "pass/DE-NO-RS-BE-FI-PT-BG-DK-LT-LU-HR-LV-FR-HU-SE-SI-ME-SK-GB-IE-MK-EE-CH-GR-IT-ES-AT-CZ-PL-RO-NL-TR-BA/**adult/2ndclass**",
    "pass/DE-NO-RS-BE-FI-PT-BG-DK-LT-LU-HR-LV-FR-HU-SE-SI-ME-SK-GB-IE-MK-EE-CH-GR-IT-ES-AT-CZ-PL-RO-NL-TR-BA/**youth/2ndclass**"
];

var results = [];

for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var matches = arr[i].match(/\*\*(.+)\/(.+)\*\*/);
    if(matches && matches.length >= 3) 
    results.push([matches[1], matches[2]]);
}

console.log(results);
```

You can try the code here https://jsfiddle.net/p84eftL7/1/

Comment: Thanks for this Syncro. I could see in the console

Im trying to use this in a function () { but so far i'm a bit stuck and I have replaced the piece of info at the top by a javascript variable as you can see below

Any idea what i'm doing wrong, as i'm not getting the values back

function () {
var arr = 
  {{CJ - ecommerce.checkout.products.category}}
  ;

  var results = [];

  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var matches = arr[i].match(/\*\*(.+)\/(.+)\*\*/);
  if(matches && matches.length >= 3) 
     results.push([matches[1], matches[2]]);
  }
 return(results);
}

Answer (score 0):

In the end what I did was the following

As I had to reference back to the name of the variable I used the following to slice up the array so I could reference that using index numbers for the values I needed to retrieve:

```
function() { 
var myStringArray = {{MY_ARRAY}};
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
var output = []
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
var string = myStringArray[i].split("/",4)
/*pull index 2 and 3 from string and convert to string*/
output.push(string) 
}
return output
}
```

After that I had to loop the new array that was being pushed out of the info as mentioned above

Since I only needed to split up particular indices from that NEW_ARRAY_2, I used the following to do that

```
function() {
var products = {{NEW_ARRAY_2}};

var arr = []  
for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++) {
var prod = products[i];
var matches = prod[2];
arr.push(matches);
}
var list = arr.join(', ')  
return list 
}
```

SAMPLE RETURN for 2 products: 'adult, youth'

Thank you for your support